# AVG Cloudcare unable to load policy

Tags: windows-server-2008, avg

I'm unable to install AVG Cloud care on a Windows Server 2008 machine. The install keeps failing at **Unable to load policy**.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just spoken with AVG Support and it is apparently related to root certificates.

If you install the windows KB931125 update at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29434 you should be good to go!